Query nested Matrix entry relations via GraphQL
I'm trying to create a GraphQL query to find nested entries stored in a Matrix field. In my case, I want to find all the albums that have a particular song in its tracklist. According to this comment, Craft 5.x has full support for this.
I'm having trouble finding documentation or examples, though. There's a short section on the docs page that provides a Twig example using target and field, but the GraphQL docs suggest using relatedToEntries relatedViaField. I also found a GitHub commit comment with an example which looks a lot like what I want, but it's returning all the albums, not just the ones with the target song in the tracklist.
# Note: $slug here is the slug of the song

query ($slug: [String]) {
  entries(
    section: "albums"
    relatedToEntries: {
      section: "songs"
      slug: $slug
      relatedViaField: "tracklist" <- The album's matrix field
    }
  )
}

What am I missing here?

OK, found out how to do it through a ton of trial and error:
query ($slug: [String]) {
  song: entry(section: "songs", slug: $slug) {
    slug
    title
  }
  relatedAlbums: entries(
    section: "albums"
    relatedToEntries: [
      { section: "songs", slug: $slug, relatedViaField: "tracklist" }
    ]
  ) {
    slug
    title
  }
}

